# Filters in a boolean ring?

Tags: ring-theory, order-theory

It is well known that boolean algebras are equivalent to boolean rings, and that furthermore order theoretic ideals in a boolean algebra $B$ correspond to ideals in $B$ seen as a boolean ring. It is natural to then ask what do order theoretic filters correspond to, when seeing them from a ring theory perspective.

A simple answer is "ideals in the ring $B^{op}$". After unravelling that, we see that a filter $F$ in a boolean ring $B$ is a non-empty set such that:

1. $a,b \in F \implies 1+a+b \in F$. (subgroup condition)
2. $a \in F, b \in B \implies a + ab + b \in F$. (absorption condition)

Is this definition relevant in general? Can this be restated in a nice/intuitive way using common ring theory concepts? A related question is, are there any interesting relations between $B$ and $B^{op}$ from a ring theory point of view?

Comment: Aren't Boolean rings always commutative?

Comment: @LukasHeger Yes, but $B^{op}$ here is the opposite in the order sense. I don't think it is isomorphic to $B$ in general as rings, since they are not isomorphic in general as boolean algebras.

Comment: Okay, I see. That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A filter in a Boolean ring is exactly a [saturated multiplicatively closed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicatively_closed_set).

Every filter $F$ is a multiplicatively closed set, since $\top =  1\in F$ and if $a,b\in F$, then $a\wedge b = ab \in F$. Indeed, a filter is exactly an upwards-closed multiplicative set. So it remains to show that a multiplicatively closed set is saturated if and only if it is upwards closed.

Suppose $F$ is upwards closed. If $ab\in F$, then since $ab\leq a$, $a\in F$, and similarly $b\in F$. So $F$ is saturated. Conversely, suppose $F$ is a saturated. If $a\in F$ and $a\leq b$, then $ab = a \in F$, so $b\in F$ by saturation. Thus $F$ is upwards closed.

Comment: Very interesting that this would work for the more general case of join semilattices and commutative idempotent monoids, while the ideals require the very strong requirement of boolaen-ness.

Comment: @FernandoChu You mean meet semilattices, right? I think the asymmetry is a result of the asymmetry between $+$ and $\cdot$ in Boolean rings (as opposed to Boolean algebras): $\cdot$ is $\wedge$, while $+$ is not $\vee$.

Comment: Oops yeah I meant meet semilattices. Good observation too!

Answer (score 3):

If you interpret it directly in terms of $B$ first, it seems like some species of **multiplicatively closed sets.**

The first condition $a,b\in F\implies ab\in F$ makes it multiplicative, of course.

For the second condition, $a\leq r\implies r\in F$: it can be interpreted as $ar=a\implies r\in F$, which I guess means $F$ contains everything that acts like an identity on one of its elements.

A *saturated* multiplicatively closed set of $B$ would satisfy this, for example.

Neither of the conditions as you stated them ring any bells for me, ring theoretically.

---

I erased an earlier comment talking about partially ordered rings because I realized that the order in boolean algebras given by $a\leq b \iff ab=a$ isn't compatible with multiplication the way it has to be for a partially ordered ring.  But nevertheless it is interesting to talk about rings with a preorder on elements given by $a\leq b\iff (a)\subseteq (b)$.

I not sure if there are any tricks for defining a filter on a preorder. [This is what I was looking at.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1900659/29335) But if one can talk about a filter $F$ in this preorder (commutative rings only), then we are lucky that $(a)\cap (b)=(ab)$ so that $F$ is multiplicatively closed (a.k.a. closed under meets, in this case). Secondly, the condition that $a\leq r\implies r\in F$ can be rewritten as $rs\in F\implies r\in F$, which is the condition for being saturated.

So it really seems that they are related to saturated multiplicative sets. But maybe I have overlooked something subtle about the preorder or the potential difficulties with the definition of a filter for preorders.  I look forward to feedback.

Comment: Indeed the filters are exactly the saturated multiplicatively closed sets (see my answer).

Comment: @AlexKruckman Ha, it seems we simultaneously arrived at the same conclusion.  I only saw your comment after I submitted my edit.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I suppose the difficulty is, in defining a filter for preorders, that $a\wedge b$ and $a\vee b$ are not uniquely defined.  Maybe one has to require their existence and then that all the meets get pulled in, and that's a workable definition?  I suppose if I forget about having the filter be on elements of $R$ and just let it be the poset of principal ideals, things might be ok.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the relevance of preorders here. In a  Boolean ring $R$, the relation $a\leq b$ iff $ab=a$ is a partial order, and $R$ is a Boolean algebra under this partial order.

Comment: Oh, maybe we just have different interpretations of the question. I was answering the question "is there a purely ring-theoretic concept which agrees with filters in the special case of Boolean rings", while maybe you are answering "if we take the usual definition of filter and try to make sense of it in an arbitrary ring, what do we get?"

Comment: @AlexKruckman I was suspicious enough of the saturated multiplicative set condition that I thought investigating it might clarify things.  I think there are probably conditions far more relaxed than being a boolean ring that allow this to be true.  Being boolean simplifies it a lot, of course. Now finally I'm curious to know what the gap is between this picture of filters and saturated multiplicative sets for commutative rings generally.